# Can I watch a video on my Mac but have the audio go through my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, audio

I would like to get the sound from my MacBook Pro to play on my iPhone. For example if I watch a video on my Mac I would be able to view it on my Mac but get the audio through my iPhone. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it.

You need to be on the same WiFi network and use a pair of matched applications on your Mac and iPhone.

The best known of these are Airfoil (for the Mac) and Airfoil Speakers Touch on your iPhone. See this: http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/

Note that Airfoil Speakers Touch **does not** turn your iPhone into Airplay speakers so you can only stream to it from a computer running Airfoil and not, for example, your iPad.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Airfoil worked decently but the delay of about 3 seconds made it unusable for watching a video.

Comment: That's pretty bad lag. I think I got mine down to less than a second and could adjust that out inside Plex and VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with Airplay if jailbroken.
If your application cannot do this by default, you could use a program like AirFoil / AirFoil Speakers - you only have to be connected on the same wifi network.

This is something I use in my own situation.

Comment: You can't use Airplay unless you jailbreak the iPhone. Apple does not allow any app that runs the iPhone into an Airplay **target** rather than source.

Comment: @TonyWilliams as I said, AirFoil can do this and I'm using this without Jailbreak. As long as you're on the same wifi network it will work.

Comment: That's **not** using Airplay. Rogue Amoeba's Airfoil uses AirPlay where available but actually does it's own streaming to Airfoil Touch on iOS devices.